# Extract group of number from text

Tags: .net, regex

Having such a text

```
Above includes - Add/Remove Member To/From Nested Group - 1.24.12 / 1.24.13
```

how do I create a regular expression that would return the 2 groups of 3 numbers I have.
Expected result

```
1.24.12
1.24.13
```

I tried to use such an expression

```
private static Regex MRDNumbers = new Regex(@"((\d+.?){2,})+");
```

but it doesn't work as needed.

Also, the length of the group can be different, it can be

```
1.22
13.4.7
1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4.5
1.2.3.4.5.6
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: I do get back only 
1.24.12 
12
here is the source code I use. http://pastebin.com/0S7pRMrk

Comment: You are confusing matches with groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `.` in your pattern. In the regular expression language, the `.` character matches any character (except in single-line mode), so you have to escape it with a `\` character to match just periods.

Try this instead:

```
private static Regex MRDNumbers = new Regex(@"((\d+\.?){2,})+");
```

To capture all the matched numbers in a list, you might try this:

```
private Regex MRDNumbers = new Regex(@"(\d+?)(?:\.(\d+))+");

string input = "Above includes - Add/Remove Member To/From Nested Group - 1.24.12 / 1.24.13";
MRDNumbers.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Dump();
var list = 
    (from m in MRDNumbers.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
     select 
     from g in m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1)
     from c in g.Captures.Cast<Capture>()
     select c.Value)
    .ToList(); 
// [ [ 1, 24, 12 ], [ 1, 24, 12 ] ]
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var list = 
    MRDNumbers.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
              .Select(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>()
                            .Skip(1)
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Captures.Cast<Capture>())
                            .Select(c => c.Value))
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, problem solved, I did use a wrong idea in C#. Here is the correct code

```
private static Regex MRDNumbers = new Regex(@"((\d+\.?){2,})+");
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = " Above includes - Add/Remove Member To/From Nested Group - 1.24.12 / 1.24.13.45 45.78";
    MatchCollection m = MRDNumbers.Matches(s);

    foreach (Match match in m)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your `.`:

```
((\d+\.?){2,})+
```

Notice that `.` is now `\.`. Seems to be [working in regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%28%5Cd%2b%5C.?%29%7B2,%7D%29%2b&input=Above%20includes%20-%20Add/Remove%20Member%20To/From%20Nested%20Group%20-%201.24.12%20/%201.24.13).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
\d+(\.\d+)+
```

You can get a list of such numbers with this code

```
List<String> lst=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your dot and one of the groups. The reason you are getting out `1.24.12 12` is that `12` is the last match that fills group 2, so you get that spit out.

Try this one:

```
private static Regex MRDNumbers = new Regex(@"((?:\d+\.?){2,})+");
```